Moses death- Numbers 27:12
Why didn't God forgive Moses and Aaron for striking the Meribah rock yet He had forgiven the Israelites countless times for dishonouring Him?

Is this any different from https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/what-exactly-did-moses-do-wrong-at-meribah?

Of course Moses was forgiven - but was punished as an example to others - there had to be consequences.

Did he forgive them?  Only Joshua and Caleb made it all the way from Egypt to the Promised Land.

Hope, I would rethink your question by giving a greater context to this event from scripture. An even wider view of this situation would include the many examples of God's judgment among Israel during this time period. One example of Israel being judged by God after leaving Egypt was when Moses came down from the mountain with the stone tablets. God threatened then to wipe out the entire nation.

Consider including scripture(s) in your question to give a setting wherein the reader can do less research on their own in order to understand what you mean to ask in your question.
For example, I believe it's an incorrect assumption that God forgave the others so readily and I found this by reading examples of his judgment during this time period. The question you have here does not factually include this but rather glosses over all of these other instances of God's anger against Israel. This lack of information then dilutes the question's usefulness to find true understanding.

Forgiven men still often have to bear the consequences of their previous sinful actions. David, "a man after God's own heart", was disciplined for his sin.  For instance: [2Sa 12:10 KJV] Now therefore the sword shall never depart from thine house; because thou hast despised me, and hast taken the wife of Uriah the Hittite to be thy wife.  A drunk who repents doesn't automatically get his liver healed.
The penalty for sin has to be paid - thankfully, now Christ has born that punishment for those who believe in His name.
